# HTML5 Canvas 2D Camera and only rendering things on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently working on a game and it's REALLY simple and quite small. But I really want some levels to be bigger than the actual size of the viewport. For example, my canvas size is 740x440 but I actually want a level that's really like 2000x440.

So I tried to simulate a basic 2D camera using the .translate() method. It's working okay but the performance is really terrible, probably because I'm rendering everything at once.

Is the .translate() the way to go? If so, then what's a good way to render things that are only being viewed by the camera?

Answer (score 0):

You should think about "layers", which are multiple canvases stacked on top of each other. That way, each animation is independent per layer.

Let's say you have a character that moves within the viewport but doesn't move away the landscape. You can have the character in one layer, the landscape in the other and animate only the character layer. That way, only the character is redrawn and not the entire scene.

Comment: Wouldn't multiple canvases would be really, really slow? I do like the idea of layers, etc. but stacking up canvases seem inefficient to me

Comment: @Dropped43 is has advantages. [KineticJS even uses this method](http://www.kineticjs.com/how-it-works.php) for better performance.

Comment: Just curious. Do you know if it makes a difference on the mobile devices? I know a single canvas is just terrible but does using multiple help at all?

Comment: @Dropped43 yes. In canvas, the whole scene gets repainted per frame. That's costly, especially when redrawing items that didn't move at all. That's why layers are done so that only portions that move are animated, saving you processing cycles.

Comment: I'm considering trying multiple canvases now. By the way, do you think I should still use .translate() to move the viewport/camera around?